# How to save python process for debug?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

In the PyCharm debugger we can pause a process. I have a program to debug that takes a lot of time before we arrive to the part I'm debugging.

The program can be modeled like that: `GOOD_CODE -> CODE_TO_DEBUG`.

I'm wondering if there is a way to..

- run GOOD_CODE
- save the process
- edit the code in CODE_TO_DEBUG
- restore the process and with the edited CODE_TO_DEBUG

Is serialization the good way to do it or is there some tool to do that?

I'm working on `OSX` with `PyCharm`.

Thank you for your kind answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic method is to write a program that reproduces the conditions that lead into the buggy code, without taking a bunch of time -- say, read in the data from a file instead of generating it -- and then paste in the code you're trying to fix.  If you get it fixed in the test wrapper, and it still doesn't work in the original program, you then "only" have to find the interaction with the rest of the program that's faulty (global variables, bad parameters passes, etc.)